# Find a DataGridView cell

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

How do I find a cell with a specific content in a DataGridView?

Comment: Server side or client side?  Some information on the scenario and what you want to do with it would help.

Comment: Sounds like a server-side question as going through the output of a gridview on the client will be an unecessary pain

Comment: Sounds like a WinForm question to me.

Comment: Makes sense @Jay Riggs. My answer below *should* work on a winform too.

Comment: Not sure why downvoted. If I can improve the question, just tell me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ariel is right on, you will have to iterate through the [GridViewRowCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewrowcollection.aspx) and then each cell of the individual GridViewRow, you can get the cell's text property or like Ariel mentioned if it is a control use FindControl and extract the appropriate property

Answer (score 5):

I dont know of a way to find a cell by content so you'll have to iterate through the cells and look for the value you need. You can use the `.FindControl()` method to find actual controls (label, literal, checkbox, etc) inside cells or go through them by index `GridView.Rows.Cells[index]`

Edit: This answer will work on an ASP.NET page (tested) and *should* work in a winform (untested)